# Отмена задачи в Task через определенное время

Tags: c#, многопоточность, task

Есть массив Task, и мне например нужно чтобы каждый Task жил 30 секунд. Как мне создать Токен для отмены каждой задачи в массиве? Так получается отменить только одну задачу, и потом ловлю исключение

```
        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = source.Token;
        Console.WriteLine("Основной поток запущен");
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
            task[i] = new Task( () =>
            {
                MyTask();

            },token);
            task[i].Start();
        }

        Task.WaitAll(task);

        Console.WriteLine("Основной поток завершен");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Какое исключение?

Comment: CancellationTokenSource, связанный с этим CancellationToken, был уничтожен.

Comment: @Kureid а зачем вы его уничтожаете?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Я подключаюсь по wmi к компьютерам(300 штук), и почему-то некоторые подключения, зависают поток на 10 минут. Хотя другие компы, которые выключены или включены, обрабатываются в нормальном режиме. Скорость обработки сильно увеличивается, если как-нибудь не проверять этот поток. Я думал дать каждому потоку время жизни 30 секунд, за это время все данные спарсятся с нужной мне машины. Вся эта обработка занимается максимум 3 минуты, а если поток завис, то 10-15 минут.

Comment: @Kureid вы не ответили - зачем вы уничтожали `CancellationTokenSource`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я бы сделал как-то так:

```
using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
{
    var ct = cts.Token;
    tasks =
        Enumerable.Range(0, 300)
                  .Select(i => Task.Run(() => MyTask(ct), ct));
    cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    catch (AggregateException)
    {
    }
}
```

Если нужно игнорировать отмену, то используйте

```
async Task IgnoreCancellation(Task t)
{
    try
    {
        await t;
    }
    catch (OperationCancelledException)
    {
    }
}
```

и пишите `IgnoreCancellation(Task.Run(...))`.

---

Дополнение: Как правильно заметил @Alexander Petrov, у вас `CancellationToken` не передаётся в `MyTask`. Это неправильно. `Task`'и и `async`/`await` реализуют по сути разновидность *кооперативной* многозадачности: каждое задание должно сотрудничать, и само управлять выполнением. Таким образом, вы должны передавать токен вовнутрь, и `MyTask` **обязан** проверять токен время от времени, и обрываться, если его об этом попросят, самостоятельно. *Остановить* запущенный `Task` невозможно, можно лишь *попросить* его остановиться самостоятельно.

Для вашего случая, это может выглядеть, например, так:

```
void MyTask(CancellationToken ct)
{
    foreach (var x in data)
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        // обработать элемент данных x.
    }
}
```

Или если `MyTask` работает асинхронно, например, так:

```
async Task MyTask(CancellationToken ct)
{
    foreach (var x in data)
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await InternalProcessing(x, ct); // обязательно передать токен дальше!
    }
}
```

Comment: Влад, у автора вопроса token не передаётся в MyTask. Наверняка он извне надеется убивать задачи. Так что расписывай, как правильно это делать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Хорошая идея, дополнил ответ. Спасибо!