# Можно ли отменить Task без CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, task

Разбираюсь с отменой задач. С CancellationToken получилось сделать отмену, но с циклом, где в каждой итерации проверяю на отмену задачи. Теперь же не понимаю, как отменить ожидание одной большой задачи. Например, когда к нам от сервера приходит один большой Json.

Пример кода:

```
private async Task LoadDataExecute() 
{
    dialogService.Show("SuperView", OnCancelDialog);    

    //Как убрать ожидание в этой строчке, если в dialogService пользователь кликнул по отмене загрузки данных?
    var models = await GetModelsAsync();
}

private void OnCancelDialog()
{
    //Отменить загрузку данных
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<SuperModel>> GetModelsAsync() 
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    //Что-то делаем
}
```

Comment: Почему вы хотите без токена делать? А так, отменить просто, когда токен подает команду на завершение, то все, кто с ним работают, выдадут ошибку `TaskCanceledException` и тем самым прекратят работу, вам достаточно ее отловить и обработать. Небольшой [пример накидал](https://pastebin.com/ZRN0jj2S). Также у вас речь идет про циклы. там если не используется асинхронная задача, которая выдаст ошибку, то просто проверяйте в начала итерации свойство `IsCancellationRequested`, если оно `true`, то делаете `break` или `return`, что завершит цикл/задачу. Например `while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested){ }`

Comment: Если вам надо перезапустить задачу, то просто даем команду на отмену старого токена и создаем новый, подобное я делал к примеру [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1166526/220553).

Comment: Приведенный код не отражает сути вопроса. И вопрос не ясен, что именно вы хотите получить? Покажите реальный код и обозначьте конкретную проблему, которую вам не удается решить. Например, укажите метод, который хотите прервать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо ваш код работает. Я и не думал, что задача завершится без проверки в теле метода на IsCancellationRequested. Не знаю, что там за магия под капотом, но обязательно в скором времени узнаю. Спасибо еще раз!

Comment: Ответом тогда напишите что у вас получилось.

Answer (score 0):

```
private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;

private async Task LoadDataExecute() 
{
    _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    dialogService.Show("SuperView", OnCancelDialog);    

    var models = await GetModelsAsync();
}

private void OnCancelDialog()
{
    _tokenSource.Cancel();
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<int>> GetModelsAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000, token);
        return Enumerable.Range(1, _rand.Next(5, 10));
    }
    catch(TaskCanceledException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Спасибо EvgeniyZ

Comment: На будущее, не стоит делать отлов всех ошибок и тем более не стоит выдавать новый, пустой объект. Все конечно зависит от вашей логики и конкретно вашей ситуации, но представьте, что вы работаете в команде, человек вызывает написанный вами метод и получает в ответ  `Enumerable.Empty<int>()`, ну он думает "Ага, значит тут все отработало хорошо, просто нету объектов, которые надо пока выводить", оставляет этот код и... получает в итоге "баг", который ооочень долго будет потом править, не понимая что и как. Лучше обрабатывать конкретные ошибки, в которых уверены, а другие пробрасывать выше.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, вообще странно, в вопросе речь была о том, чтобы не использовать  CancellationToken, а в ответе - они все так же используются

Comment: @Grundy Согласен, но если присмотреться, то там в основном суть в том, что автор не знает, как делать остановку запущенной таски, где он не может проверить `IsCancellationRequested` сам. То есть, можно переформулировать его как `Можно ли отменить Task без проверки IsCancellationRequested?`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, так ответ на самом деле - нельзя :) потому что тут - эти делом занимается внутренний таск, ну и можно и не проверять это флаг а вызывать [.ThrowIfRequested](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested?view=netcore-3.1), то есть если никто не проверят CancelationToken - то и прервать таск нельзя

Comment: @Grundy Ну это уже тонкости реализации. Вообще, я хотел дубликат найти, да только вот не нашел адекватного, с подробным описанием, если найдете, то думаю можно будет смело закрывать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, не такой? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/651951/186999 или вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/816785/186999

Comment: @Grundy Увы, информативности в них мало, лишь, что без токена не закрыть, а как конкретно это делать упомянуто лишь вскользь и то ссылками. Я не думаю, что автору это помогло бы понять суть проблемы.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а если вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654754/186999 или вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573579/186999 ?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Или вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521468/186999

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, во, похоже вот оно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612953/186999

Comment: @Grundy Первая явно не в ту степь пошло. Вторая больше про потоки, а не таски, сами таски там опять вскользь упоминаются. Третья ссылка, там лишь код, без какого либо объяснения. А вот последняя, ближе всего, но лично мне не хватает информативности, так что да, можно на него закрыть, и под вопрос подходит с "Вы не можете «отменить» уже бегущий код" и показывает как работать с токенами.